# What do these words mean as German language knowledge level?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, technical-terminology

Can you please help me to know what these words mean exactly as German **proficiency level**: Foreign language A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2? 
Because while I’m looking for any job vacancy I see these words and I asked my German teacher, but she doesn’t know so can you please help me

- *Verhandlungssicheres Deutsch*
- *Sicheres Deutsch*
- *Gutes Deutsch*
- *Sehr gutes Deutsch*
- *Fließend Deutsch*

Answer (score 10):

Actually, there is no such thing as a *defined mapping* between European Common Language Levels and such expressions typically used in job adverts. The levels distinguish between active and passive control of the language as well as reading/writing and conversational skills, this is not normally expressed in job adverts - The following mapping is mine and might be disputable:

- A1: "Deutschkentnisse"
- A2: "gute Grundkenntnisse"
- B1: "konversationssicher"
- B2: "fließend", "gute Deutschkenntnisse"
- C1: "fließend in Wort und Schrift", "sicheres Deutsch"
- C2: "verhandlungssicher", "sehr gutes Deutsch" (is maybe C1, though), "perfekte Deutschkenntnisse"

This mapping is entirely subjective and according to my personal experience - Your mileage may vary. In the end, the only thing that counts is the subjective mapping table the receiver of your application has in mind. In case you have an A/B/C certificate, it doesn't hurt mentioning it.

> Sichere Beherrschung der deutschen Sprache

is a term often used in job adverts - IMHO, that would be B2+/C1 at least.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) to the various levels put forth by the Common European Reference Framework for Languages. The following interpretations are mine.

A. Beginner

A-1 Knows only the most basic phrases and expressions. Can converse after a fashion on a handful of topics.

A-2. Has a limited command of vocabulary and expressions that goes beyond "basic." Can function in a broader range of situations than an A-1. Can sustain a conversation, or write a passage, of modest length and depth.

B. Intermediate

B-1. Has a level of proficiency that is good enough for "familiar," ordinary, or everyday situations. Can "get along" in the language, although with some difficulty.

B-2. Beginning to exhibit proficiency or mastery in complex topics, particularly those related to one's interests or profession. Can handle most situations without difficulty. Mistakes and "accent" are starting to "go away."

C. Advanced/Fluent

C-1. Has a deep understanding of both the vocabulary and the structure of the language, and can use the language fluently. Is able to express oneself clearly and accurately using complex constructions in many situations. Makes only occasional mistakes.

C-2 Proficient across a wide range of topics, almost, but not quite as fluent as a well-educated native speaker. Mistakes are rare, almost non-existent.

In US State Department terms, someone with a B2/C1 level has "professional" proficiency, and someone with a C2 level has "full professional" proficiency.