# "es ist/sind" versus "da ist/sind" to mean there is/are

Tags: difference, pronoun, expletiva

These two questions ([1](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6806/difference-between-es-sind-and-es-gibt-for-asserting-existence-of-something), [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/es-gibt-vs-da-ist-da-sind)) are close to what I’m trying to pin down. But I want to know if there is any significant difference between “es ist/sind” and “da ist/sind”.

For example, I found these two examples in the dictionary:

> Geh vorsichtig um mit den Kartons, ***da*** sind zerbrechliche Sachen drin.
>   „Ist jemand im Badezimmer?“ – „Nein, ***es*** ist niemand drinnen“.

But can I say it, for instance, the other way round:

> ***Es*** sind zerbrechliche Sachen drin.
>   ***Da*** ist niemand drinnen.

Are *es* and *da* interchangeable in this construction? If not, what’s the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually no, you cannot interchange the words. But you can use both variants.

*Da* refers to the object in question, the box or the bathroom, respectively.

> Geh vorsichtig um mit den Kartons, dadrin [=in den Kartons] sind zerbrechliche Sachen.
>
> Ist jemand im Badezimmer? - Nein, dadrinnen [=im Badezimmer] ist niemand.

*Es*, in contrast, is something different. It is an [expletive subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive). It does not have any meaning, and only exists for grammatical reasons.

> Geh vorsichtig um mit den Kartons, es sind zerbrechliche Sachen dadrin [=in den Kartons].
>
> Ist jemand im Badezimmer? - Nein, es ist niemand dadrinnen [=im Badezimmer].

As you see I still use *da* in those sentences. You can indeed drop *da-* without changing the meaning but I didn't omit them to make clear that *es* is not a replacement for *da*.

So, what your actually doing is rewording the sentence.

> Im Badezimmer ist niemand. => Es ist niemand im Badezimmer.

And as you mentioned *Im Badezimmer* before and don't want to repeat, you replace *im Badezimmer* mit *dadrinnen*.

> Dadrinnen ist niemand. => Es ist niemand dadrinnen.

Comment: So in case of _da ist/sind_ you kind of split "**dadrin**" in two halves "**da** [bla-bla] **drin**". Thus, _dadrin sind zerbrechliche Sachen_ becomes _da sind zerbrechliche Sachen drin_?

Comment: @stillenat Basically yes. But note that *dadrin* is colloquial for *darin* and you cannot split the latter one.