# Does the differentiation of "es gibt" vs "ist" follow the same principles that "es gibt" vs "da ist"?

Tags: verb-choice

There are a number of questions related to "es gibt" vs "da ist". I think there are cases where only "ist", and not "da ist" can be used, and wonder what rules on how to differentiate to "es gibt" apply on these cases:

> In diesem Glas ist wenig Wasser.

I'm not sure if "In diesem Glas" could be replaced by "da", ending up with an equivalent sentence. I've also heard:

> Morgen ist kein Fußball.

Meaning that we won't play tomorrow. I think there is no way of using "da ist" with this sentence. But I would have never said like that, I'd have said "Morgen gibt es kein Fußball".

Why is "ist" used in this sentence, because Fußball is not abstract (following the abstract/actual concept explained [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7378/26295))?

Comment: Where is the connection of *»In diesem Glas ist wenig Wasser«* with *»es gibt«*?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I would say _In diesem Glas gibt es wenig Wasser_ I know is wrong because I've seen _In diesem Glas ist wenig Wasser_, but not why.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know when to use **es gibt** and when **es ist**, right?

> Es gibt noch viel zu tun.
>
> Es ist noch viel zu tun.
>
> Da ist noch viel zu tun.

*There is much left to do.*

All three sentences are valid. The difference ist *da* is pointing a finger to something while both *es gibt* and *es ist* just state the fact. So, playing with *da* doesn't help you here.

---

To understand the German, better take a step back from English *there is*:

> In der Oase gibt es Wasser.

*The oasis has water.*

> In der Oase ist Wasser.

*The oasis is filled with water.*

This means such a weird thing because the phrase *In A ist B.* means A is a container filled with B. So you have to use *es gibt* here, which uses the oasis as a backdrop rather than a container.

> Auf dem Dachboden gibt es Mäuse.
>
> Auf dem Dachboden sind Mäuse.

Both sentences are valid, but the first uses the attic as a backdrop for the fact "mice exist". The latter instead states mice are in the attic.