# "there are" usage without "es gibt"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is there any difference between the following two sentences in terms of the meaning and where they might have been used?:

> In dieser Stadt sind schon viele schöne alte Häuser

and

> In dieser Stadt gibt es schon viele schöne alte Häuser

Comment: Maybe https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/es-gibt-vs-da-ist-da-sind covers this already.

Comment: Along with  this one, it cover it: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/6806/43272

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to search for this type of question before I had asked the above question